# jquery autocomplete with json data not displayed

Tags: jquery

I have json format like this

```
"results1": [{
    "title": "beach",
    "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/RND\/wordpress\/hotel-category\/beach\/"
}], "results2": [{
    "title": "",
    "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/RND\/wordpress\/hotel-item\/best-hotel\/"
}]
}
```

I want to show this data in jquery autocomplete.
Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I have used this code

Comment: $.each(data, function(result,items) {
     response( $.map( items, function( item ) {
     return {
                    label: item.title,
                    value: item.title,
                    url: item.url
                   }
         
               } 
      ));
     });